# How to identity performance bottleneck with PHP slowness on linux?

Tags: php, cifs

On my linux server, I have a PHP process which is taking way too long (multiple days) to complete. The script basically splits a large data file into small chunks and writes into corresponding files onto a CIFS filesystem (network share). I am trying to troubleshoot using strace on the relevant PID and I see the following based on which it appears that most of the time is consumed in the writes:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
89.88   17.722953           4   4854316           write
10.07    1.985505           1   2427149           lseek
0.05    0.009307           1      7706           read
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00   19.717765               7289171           total
```

How can I debug this further to identify the bottleneck? Is there any obvious PHP configuration that I need to check out? The php.ini file on the server currently has all the default settings (e.g. output_buffering = 4096). Not sure if I need to make any changes there.

Any suggestions to troubleshoot this further would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your bottleneck is fairly obviously IO and there aren't any PHP settings that you can tweak that will make your disk go faster.

Comment: Have you tried writing the files to a local file system and see what happens.

Comment: Infact, I have a test running to exactly that (write to local FS) and looks like a much faster operation. Appears to be IO bottleneck with the CIFS FS. Thanks for the comments.